# How to freeze and resume a process

Tags: freeze, cgroups

According to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/796750/freeze-and-unfreeze-processes-transparently) and [its accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/796770/261445), following script should suspend and resume the `btrfs send` process:

```
#!/bin/bash 

get_ms () {
    echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
}

START_TIME=$(get_ms)


echo "starting btrfs send to file"
btrfs send -p rootfs/rootfs.20170429T2001 rootfs/rootfs.20170430T0140 -f test.snapshot &
PID=$!
echo "PID is: $PID"

mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/0
echo $PID > /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/0/tasks

pause () {
    echo "pausing process $PID"
    echo FROZEN > /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/0/freezer.state
}

resume () {
    echo "resuming process $PID"
    echo THAWED > /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/0/freezer.state
}

is_alive () {
    if [[ "$(ps -o pid= -p $PID)" == "$PID" ]]; then 
        return 0
    else 
        return 1
    fi
}

on_exit () {
    kill -9 $PID
}

trap on_exit INT


while is_alive; do 
    echo "$PID is still alive..."
    sleep 0.1
    pause
    read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
    resume
done

echo "Took $(($(get_ms) - $START_TIME)) ms..."
```

However, if we commend out `pause` to `resume` lines in the loop, this process takes 1.5 seconds and generates a 244MB file output.

If we use the script as is, the output file size stops at a reasonable size, when we hit `Enter` button, it grows and stops at a higher reasonable size; but it won't stop growing (I just killed the script after +380MB)

How can I stop (freeze) the process and then continue?

Comment: Are you sure `mount|grep freezer` shows `cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer ...`.

Comment: yes, it shows: 
`cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)`

Answer (score 1):

In general (I don't know about `btrfs` or how it works under the hood with a process that does extreme amounts of disk IO) one may temporarily stop a process whose PID is `$pid` with

```
kill -TSTP "$pid"
```

The process may then be resumed with

```
kill -CONT "$pid"
```

Comment: There lots of questions about suspending and resuming a linux process and this answer is given on those questions, right. I did try to use these signals en the first hand but result is same at minimum, application (btrfs) continued writing data to the output file after killing(???) at most... (then I killed btrfs with `ps -ef | grep btrfs` then `kill -9 xxx`)

Comment: @ceremcem If the kernel has started to write on the behalf of the `btrfs` process, that writing will not stop when you stop the process (that would seriously lock the kernel and disk up). On a side note: "killing" with `kill` just means sending a signal. It will not necessarily terminate the target process, depending on what signal is sent and what the process does when it receives it.

Comment: my last resort is setting up a virtual machine, running `btrfs` (or any program I need to suspend) in that VM, and suspend the whole VM. That would be the silver bullet.

Comment: @ceremcem You could try that, but it will be a similar problem between the VMM running on the host and the host disk (and kernel).